# Retrieving api's response in json format

Tags: php, json, api

I am using the **campaign monitor's api** and trying to retrieve the response in a `json` format, which it is supposed to do. I echoed the response, here's an example :

```
string(342) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: csw
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
X-CS-Node: 25
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
P3P: CP="OTI DSP COR CUR IVD CONi OTPi OUR IND UNI STA PRE"
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 12:35:10 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 66


{"Code":250,"Message":"List title must be unique within a client"}"
```

I would like to get the only last line. How can I do that ? (I tried to explode the response with a white space, but it didn't change anything).

Edit : the documentation is [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/getting-started/#response_codes), I call a method `method()`, that returns the response `$response = method()` and I run `echo($response)`

Comment: Please show some code (How do you make your call, etc.)

Comment: This isn't well formatted, by last line do you mean:
"{"Code":250,"Message":"List title must be unique within a client"}""

?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the preg_match function to search for the JSON by searching for the Regular Expression '/{.*}/'.

```
preg_match('/\{.*\}/', $response, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this example code](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/blob/master/samples/get_billing_details.php) you should be doing:

```
$result = method(); # I'm assuming you over-simplified the code in your question and "method" isn't the real method name
echo $result->response; # Not echo $result;
```

Comment: To be more explicit I tried to create a list wit this var_dump($test_list->create('client_id', $test_array)->response) but I still have the same message. What is weird is that if I run with any string var_dump($test_list->create('client_id', $test_array)->any_string, I still get the same message ??